# Wrong format in JSON String

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this piece of code

```
$bom = Foo::getFooFromName($fooName);
            $content = json_decode($foo['content'], true);
            $content[] =  $foo_name . ':'.  $qty  ;

            Foo::where('id', $foo['id'])->update([
                'content' => json_encode($content, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
            ]);
```

that when executed it fives me this JSON STRING:

```
{"0":{"171":"3"},"1":"396:3"}
```

This part already exists, so the JSON string is correct: {"0":{"171":"3"} but when I run `$content[] =  $foo_name . ':'.  $qty  ;

```
            Foo::where('id', $foo['id'])->update([
                'content' => json_encode($content, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
            ]);
```

It seems that I am unable to properly format the JSON String to look like this:

```
{"0":{"171":"3"},"1":{"396":"3"}}
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting a string to the array, while you should be inserting another array.

Replace

```
$content[] =  $foo_name . ':'.  $qty  ;
```

with

```
$content[] =  [$foo_name =>  $qty];
```